# #include dcomp.h not found

Tags: windows, graphics

I am trying to run the Microsoft DirectComposition Sample which utilizes various IDComposition_____ types. It appears that I am missing dcomp.h which contains these types. I've tried looking around for the header file, but can't seem to find it anywhere.

Am I going about this the wrong way or something?
Maybe someone can point a link towards dcomp.h..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the Windows SDK for Windows 8. It’s included with Visual Studio 2012. For other compilers you’ll need to download the SDK separately.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx